# Obtaining from definition the probability density function associated to a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The answer to this question might be simpler than I'm thinking, but for now I'm having some trouble to find it out. I'm studying probability following Shiryaev's book and I'm thinking  of the construction by the definition of the probability density function of a random variable $X(\omega)$, given the space $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$.

For simplicity, I'm imagining a model such as $(\Omega,F, \mathbb{P})$ with $\Omega = [0,1]$, $F$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{P}$ the Lebesgue measure. Then I define a random variable $X(\omega) = \omega$ and try to find its probability law. To do so, I just have to find the set of all pre-images $X^{-1}((-\infty, a]) := \{\omega \in F: X(\omega) \leq a \}$. In my case:

$$ X^{-1}\left((-\infty,a]\right) =\begin{cases}
\emptyset  & a<0 \\
a & a \in [0,1] \\
\Omega & a >1
\end{cases} $$

to which I use the Lebesgue measure to assess:

$$ P_X\left((-\infty,a]\right) =\begin{cases}
0  & a<0 \\
a & a \in [0,1] \\
1& a >1
\end{cases} $$ and it is done! I have $f_X(x)=\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(x)$ because I can find the derivative for $F_X(a) = a \mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(a)$.

Now to my question: let's say I'm working with a space like $(\Omega,F, \mathbb{P})$ with $\Omega = [1,2]\times[1,2]$, $F$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$ and again $\mathbb{P}$ is the Lebesgue measure. Now I can define a random variable $Z:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$, such that $Z(\omega) = x y$. I am having trouble writing the probability density for this kind of situation. How do I do so?

What I've thought so far: I could use the same process to write it. Like, define the set of preimages for $Z^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ and try to do as I did. Then I'd write:

$$ Z^{-1}\left((-\infty,a]\right) =\begin{cases}
\emptyset  & a<1 \\
\{\omega \in \Omega: y\leq a/x \} & a \in [1,4] \\
\Omega & a >4
\end{cases} $$

And I'd need to find the Lebesgue measure for $\{\omega \in \Omega: y\leq a/x\}$. But from here I don't know how to proceed. I'd appreciate some help. Is my idea correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing the derivative of the cumulative distribution function is indeed a way to derive the probability distribution function. Denoting by $F$ the cumulative distribution function, you have, as you said, $F(a)=0$ for $a<1$ and $F(a)=1$ for $a>4$. For $a\in[1,4]$, $F(a)$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\{(x,y)\in[1,2]^2\mid y\le a/x\}$. In other words, $F(a)$ is the area of the intersection between the square $[1,2]^2$ and what is below the hyperbola of equation $y=\frac ax$. If you draw the latter hyperbola, you see that it is natural to distinguish the cases $a\le 2$ and $a>2$.

If I'm not mistaken, you find for $a\in[1,2]$
$$
F(a)=\int_{x=1}^a\left(\frac1x-1\right)\,dx+\int_{x=a}^20\,dx=aln a-a+1,
$$
and for $a\in[2,4]$
$$
F(a)=\int_{x=1}^{a/2}1\,dx+\int_{x=a/2}^2\left(\frac1x-1\right)=a-a\ln a-3+a\ln4.
$$

By taking the derivating we have that $Z$ has probability distribution function
$$
a\mapsto\ln(a)1_{\{1\le a\le2\}}+\ln\left(\frac4a\right)1_{\{2<a\le4\}}.
$$